# external session by name joomla

Tags: php, session, joomla

i create this session with ajax

```
$_SESSION['thename'] = array();

$_SESSION['thename']['1_value1']='value 1';
$_SESSION['thename']['1_value2']='value 2';
$_SESSION['thename']['1_value3']='value 3';
$_SESSION['thename']['1_value4']='value 4';
$_SESSION['thename']['2_value5']='value 5';
$_SESSION['thename']['2_value6']='value 6';
$_SESSION['thename']['2_value7']='value 7';
$_SESSION['thename']['2_value8']='value 8';
```

I add this code lines in the top inside the php file which called from joomla.

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../..' ));

require_once ( JPATH_BASE '/includes/defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE '/includes/framework.php' );
$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();

$session = JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('thename', "value");

$session = JFactory::getSession();
echo $session->get('thename');
```

but nothings happen

I need do this inside a foreach

```
$i=0;
foreach ($_SESSION['thename'] as $key => $thevalue) {
echo "value #".$i.": ".$thevalue;
$i++;
}
```

but inside joomla

example result

```
value#1: value 1 
value#2: value 2 
value#3: value 3 
value#4: value 4 
value#5: value 5 
value#6: value 6 
value#7: value 7 
value#8: value 8
```

Comment: What do you mean *nothing happens*? Do you get any errors? What is actually happening?